# Plastic shed on undersized concrete pad?

Tags: concrete, shed, pad

I have a concrete pad that butts up against a retaining wall. The retaining overlaps slightly which reduces the size of the usable concrete pad to just under 6' in that direction.. maybe 1-2" shy.

Can I buy a 6x8 shed and get away with it hanging off an inch or two on one side? It would be anchored to the concrete on the 2 possible corners.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Anchoring should be better than just two corners.

If not at the four corners, then maybe along the sides.

I imagine this type of shed you can toss around by yourself, so wind can do the same.

The two inches should be supported underneath with cement small blocks or cement, or pressure treated wood.